# Does typescript/javascript have a @"\" equivalent like C#?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way that I can put slashes in a string in javascript without having to put two?

In C# I could do this:

```
@"This\is not used as an escape\"
```

(The @ in front of the string makes it not use \ as an escape char.)

**Is there something like this in javascript/typescript?**

Comment: No, there is not this kind of escaping

Comment: @vp_arth you should make an answer out of that. :)

Comment: `(function h(){/*"this \is a test\"*/}).toString().split("*")[1]`

Comment: @dandavis, nice. But still required some escaping. Your sample has issues with asterisks, for example.

Comment: agreed; a non-one-liner+short regexp would make it stronger, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not this kind of escaping in `javascript`

[String literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4)

Answer (score 2):

The `@` is called a verbatim string in C#. **One of the key objectives is to allow you have strings that are multiline.**

To get the same effect you use a `template string` in TypeScript / JavaScript : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html

However you would still need to escape any usages of `\`.